# can I upload firestore.rules from another file?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-cli

other than `firebase deploy --only firestore:rules` is there any other solution to upload the rules ?

the goal is to upload a different rules file without changing the project configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command only tells the Firebase *that* it should upload the Firestore rules, not which file to upload. What exact file it uploads is actually configured in the `firebase.json` file for that project. There is no way to specify the file name on the command line though.

What you *can* do is [set up multiple project aliases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#project_aliases), one for each rules file you want to use, and then either switch between the aliases with `firebase use ...` or specify the alias with a `--project=<alias>` flag.

Comment: can gcloud upload firestore rules ?

Comment: I don't think so.